# Drupal 7 Webform - Submit Button and File Upload Button break the form

Tags: forms, drupal, submit, drupal-webform

Im using Drupal 7 with Webform for forms. Today I added an file-upload to my form. Any time im uploading a file, the page reloads and the file is successfully uploaded. So I thought thats annoying and I disabled the upload button with css (display: none;). I noticed that the file will upload when im pressing the normal submit button of my form.

The problem is that both submit buttons (Submit Form and Upload File) are uploading files, nothing else. So I removed the file upload, tried the form again and it worked.

Yesterday I had the same form with my file upload and it worked too. Today its broken and I have no idea why. I havnt changed anything. I just opend my browser and testet the page.

Heres the Code of my form:

```html
<form class="webform-client-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/ppi/de/fcfay-16-free-coffee-year-ppi-media" method="post" id="webform-client-form-800" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <div>
    <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield" id="webform-component-name">
      <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-submitted-name">Name <span class="form-required" title="Diese Angabe wird benötigt.">*</span>
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-name" name="submitted[name]" value="Test" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text required">
    </div>
    <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-email" id="webform-component-e-mail">
      <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-submitted-e-mail">E-Mail</label>
      <input class="email form-text form-email" type="email" id="edit-submitted-e-mail" name="submitted[e_mail]" value="test@test.com" size="60">
    </div>
    <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield" id="webform-component-telefon">
      <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-submitted-telefon">Telefon</label>
      <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-telefon" name="submitted[telefon]" value="023847272" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield" id="webform-component-video-link">
      <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-submitted-video-link">Video Link</label>
      <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-video-link" name="submitted[video_link]" value="http://www.youtube.com" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
    </div>
    <div id="edit-submitted-datei-hochladen-ajax-wrapper">
      <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-managed_file webform-container-inline" id="webform-component-datei-hochladen">
        <label for="edit-submitted-datei-hochladen-upload">Upload</label>
        <div id="edit-submitted-datei-hochladen-upload" class="form-managed-file"><span class="file"><img class="file-icon" alt="" title="image/png" src="/ppi/modules/file/icons/image-x-generic.png"> <a href="https://censoredtheurl.de/files/webform/test/lp_1.png" type="image/png; length=428938">lp.png</a></span> 
          <input type="submit"
          id="edit-submitted-datei-hochladen-remove-button" name="submitted_datei_hochladen_remove_button" value="Entfernen" class="form-submit">
          <input type="hidden" name="submitted[datei_hochladen][fid]" value="2140">
        </div>
        <div class="description">(Max. 5MB - gif, jpg, png, eps, tif, psd, txt, rtf, pdf, doc, docx, ppt, pptx, xls, xlsx, xml, zip, rar)</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textarea" id="webform-component-nachricht">
      <label for="edit-submitted-nachricht">Nachricht</label>
      <div class="form-textarea-wrapper resizable">
        <textarea id="edit-submitted-nachricht" name="submitted[nachricht]" cols="60" rows="5" class="form-textarea">Test</textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="details[sid]">
    <input type="hidden" name="details[page_num]" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="details[page_count]" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="details[finished]" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-YNH6iMPMrKyMKzlJOvV0dPotbFQ3iM-xkGYCGeRw3Ho">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="webform_client_form_800">
    <input type="hidden" name="honeypot_time" value="1454407697|T7pTBVfnoioY6JQxJ5wOclnk_F9kcCdpclFi3C4m0fc">
    <div class="url-textfield">
      <input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Absenden" class="form-submit">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```